# Adding fields acting like tags

Tags: wordpress

I am working on news website and I would like to add two fields in the post form, one for the reporters names and other for photographers names.

I need these fields to be act exactly like tags field: you can add many and it is autocomplete.

I am not sure what is the proper way to implement such thing? and whether there Is a plugin for that or not?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create your own category/tag by using below plugin

[1. Custom Post Types and Custom Fields creator – WCK](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wck-custom-fields-and-custom-post-types-creator/)

OR

[2. Toolset Types – Custom Post Types, Custom Fields and Taxonomies](https://wordpress.org/plugins/types/)

Comment: Thank you, that was helpfull